# Substring Question - Text After Integer or Bracket

Tags: sql

I'm trying to clean Full_Name data for a column I have in SSMS. I am a complete beginner in SQL, just started learning a while ago.#

There are only three records in the Full_Name column of a table that consists of only that three records:

1. The NumberTwo Store [PARENT] : [DIST] The NumberOne Store
2. The NumberTwo Store [PARENT] : [ESTORE] AGM122358896 John Doe
3. AGM1223554489 Jim Doe

I would like to write a formula that gives the following records as a result, the name at the end of each string:

1. The NumberOne Store
2. John Doe
3. Jim Doe

**As I mentioned, I'm a beginner, below you can see what I've tried.**

```
select 

  ,Full_Name

  ,replace(substring(Full_Name,CHARINDEX (']', Full_Name), LEN(FULL_NAME)),']',' ') as GoodName2

from table
```

*I expect the output to be the values after the last (integer+space key) or if there's no integer then after the last (bracket + space key)*

This is my first post here, I hope it's alright.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Where is `Jim Doe` coming from? This doesn't appear in your sample data? Can you post your sample data more clearly?

Comment: Hi fubar, I updated my question.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (the use of `charindex` seems to indicate Microsoft SQL Server though). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Yes, it is SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It gives you the desired output:

```
SELECT REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE (SUBSTRING(Full_Name,(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Full_Name)),20), '0', ''),
'1', ''),
'2', ''),
'3', ''),
'4', ''),
'5', ''),
'6', ''),
'7', ''),
'8', ''),
'9', '')
From table
```

Comment: What am I missing? Is `REPLACE` is a function? It doesn't seem to be part of standard SQL. Can you point me to some reference regarding it?

Comment: I think it's not enough to replace. The logic I'd like if possible is to either get the string after the last integer, or if there's no integer, then the last bracket.